# Коррекция перспективы и анаморфизм средствами Unity3D

Tags: unity3d

Всем привет!

Работаю над анаморфным изображенем в юнити. Это такое изображение которое выглядит объемным с определенной точки. Беру камеру, рендерю картинку в текстуру. Затем накладываю ее на плэйн. Но камера захватывает лишнее пространство, поэтому мне нужно что бы дистанция между верхними точками области захватываемой камерой было меньше, а в идеале средство управления 4 точками визера камеры.

В реальной жизни это можно решить Sift объективом. Как подобное можно сделать в Юнити? Может есть подобная настройка линз камеры или перемещение самой камеры относительно облисти захвата изображения?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: деформировать изображение можно во фрагментном шейдере, установив зависимость координаты по x от координаты по y

Answer (score 0):

Управление 4мя точками визера камеры? Вы несёте абсолютную чушь, этих точек не существует.
Вы сначала создаёте это изображение под определённую позицию и угол, а не ищите позицию и угол под готовое. Не пытайтесь одеть штаны через голову.
Вам нужно:

- На Canvas отложить прямоугольник нормального изображения. 4 точки углов этого прямоугольника.
- Либо с помощью [ScreenToWorldPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html), либо [ViewportToWorldPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ViewportToWorldPoint.html) спроэцировать эти 4 точки в мировую координату.
- Создать [Mesh](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.html) по этим точкам и наложить материал с вашей текстурой.

И получите анаморфное изображение для камеры с выбранной позицией и поворотом.

Comment: Дело в том что у меня не текстура, а вся игра. 2 проекции, размером 1.1 на 6 метров с 1 проектора, будут располагаться на полу перед пользователем. Если встать перед одной из них то с этой точки деформированная перспектива должна собираться в обычную. Есть идеи как можно это реализовать?

Comment: Управление углами визера камеры реализовано в ассете [Camera Perspective Editor](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/particles-effects/camera-perspective-editor-16349), но он не работает с LWRP, URP.